CSS Grid that distributes cells evenly in available rows
I am trying to make a CSS grid that distributes cells evenly across available rows so that the last row is not mostly empty. The number of cells is variable and but the cell width is fixed. Container width is also responsive.
I can achieve a grid with variable columns/rows with:
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, Xrem);
But when a new row is created there is just one element in it and rest is empty.
See this for example: https://codepen.io/saurabh0/pen/MYgpZWZ
When the 8th element is added I get:
This is what I want instead:


This is not possible without a specific number of columns.

do you at least have a maximum number of items? if so, it can be possible

Yes, maximum number of items is 14.

What do you want if there are 9 items (e.g. 3 x 3 grid?), 10 items (?5x2), 11 items etc?

Since your max value is known you can write specific CSS to cover all the case. The idea is to adjust the number of columns based on the number of elements (I used my online tool to easily get the selectors: https://css-tip.com/quantity-queries/)
You can easily extend to more than 14 items following the pattern.


document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.querySelector(".container").appendChild(document.createElement("div")); 
});
.container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--n,1),auto);
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container:has(> :nth-child(2)) {--n:2}
.container:has(> :nth-child(5)) {--n:3}
.container:has(> :nth-child(7)) {--n:4}
.container:has(> :nth-child(9)) {--n:5}
.container:has(> :nth-child(11)){--n:6}
.container:has(> :nth-child(13)){--n:7}


.container > div {
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   width: 80px;
}
<button>Add</button>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>




Thank you! This was very close to what I ended up doing. Just added some media queries to account for the responsive container. Here is the code in case anyone is interested: https://codepen.io/saurabh0/pen/vEBmOxa

Try using the CSS function minmax() .
What about the following solution:
.container {
    /* Your other code */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
    column-gap: 2rem;
}



Thanks for the reply. Here you have fixed the number of columns. Depending on the container width, it could be any number of columns.
